# Fetch rows from mysql table if a condition satisfies in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have a table like this
[my table is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8Dp1.png)

I need to fetch the table such that the valid_from date is less than the the date which I have(date cannot be current date).

For example. If my date is 02-04-2015, I should get the row with id 120.
Plz help me to do this in php

Comment: in which format you save your date in database ?

Answer (score 0):

as per your example

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table_name` where validFrom < '02-04-2015' order by validFrom desc LIMIT 1
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table_name` where validFrom < '02-04-2015' order by validFrom asc LIMIT 1
```

- set order by as per your expectation of output
- here you want to pass date as per your date format

Comment: yah. but i fetches all rows that satisfies this condition. i need only one row. here for eg i need only row with id 120.  I need something like this   `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE max(validFrom) < '2015-04-03T18:30:00.000Z'`

Comment: use order by validFrom desc  LIMIT  1 or validFrom asc  LIMIT  1  as per your expectation

Comment: @athira Why doesn't it say that in the question? Your title says "rows", which means more than 1.

Comment: @athira  any answer helpful to you or give you solution please upvote it or verify it so it will helpful to anyone else

Answer (score 0):

Please try below quewry :

```
$input_date = "02-04-2015";
$your_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($input_date));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` where DATE(validFrom) < '".$your_date."'";
```